# Import/configure SSL inspection certs (regulatory)

Tags: proxy, ssl

If your company requires that all outbound SSL traffic be inspected for DLP and/or other regulatory purposes; you need to configure the proxy cert in your cert stores or key chains, this is not as simple as it is in Windows which is just import the certificate(s). RHEL and UBUNTU are very different when it comes to this also.

Comment: Trying to help others but OK let me break it up.

Answer (score 1):

RHEL and UBUNTU are very different when it comes to this also. SO be careful, I finally found an UBUNTU only tutorial that provided me the steps I needed even though my proxy is from a different vendor, I just adjusted these instructions for my environment. https://www.sonicwall.com/en-us/support/knowledge-base/171225202320465.

NOTE: Hope this helps the next poor Windows Admin trying to figure this out for their environment, nobody understood me when I originally asked for help. I see people are stickers for process.